# SONAR Violation Issue - Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable squid:S1948

Tags: java, serialization, sonarqube, transient

I am getting below Critical Sonar violation and don't know how to solve. Please help.

> **Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable** (squid:S1948)
>
> Fields in a Serializable class must themselves be either Serializable or transient even if the class is never explicitly serialized or deserialized. That's because under load, most J2EE application frameworks flush objects to disk, and an allegedly Serializable object with non-transient, non-serializable data members could cause program crashes, and open the door to attackers.
> This rule raises an issue on non-Serializable fields, and on collection fields when they are not private (because they could be assigned non-Serializable values externally), and when they are assigned non-Serializable types within the class.

Rule saying that all object must be serialize or transit ,we don’t want to make it transit since we are saving it to activity , this member is type of “Object” class and we cannot make him serialize.

Example Class:

```
public class CharacteristicData implements ICharacteristicData, Serializable {

  Object val;
  String code;
  Class<?> type; // Qualified class name
  boolean isMandatory;
  .........................
```

This class represents attributes. We can tell only in runtime its type(String , Date, Number etc... )

Comment: Try declaring `Serializable val;`  ?

Comment: Thanks. it worked. But, it seems that this is bug in SONARQUBE and needs to be fixed. we should be allowed to use internal Java objects inside serializable class.